# Is there a way to enforce generics are of a certain type in C#? Or if this is a bad pattern, what alternatives might I have?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, interface

I'm working on refactoring our code base to more generically handle a problem that we are solving for frequently. The way our codebase is set up as follows-

It has a series of classes defined with two generic classes, one representing an Entity and one representing the final mapped c# object for use in the application. The TEntity part is defined as "where TEntity: class", because the EF classes don't accept anything more specific than that (most notably, the ones that set which entity we're trying to read).

However, the case we're generically trying to handle involves a set of Entity objects that will all have similar attributes. They have a partial class on top of them that implements an ISomethingSomething interface, and the case I'm trying to generalize uses some attributes defined on this interface.

So if I have a class defined with a TEntity, and a method that leverages the classes TEntity, is there any way at all within this method that I can check for and apply a cast into an ISomethingSomething in order to solve the more general problem, and then back into the TEntity to continue the rest of the function?

Also relevant, is I am working with Entity Framework queryables. Whatever the solution is, I would like to NOT have it enumerate the list of entities, because this casting is needed to do the filtering.

Example of what I'm trying to accomplish, in hacky pseudocode:

```
public class Something<T> where T: class{
    public function SomeReturn<T> DoesTheThings<T>(Queryable<T> query){
        //where the query is on some open database context using EF
        if(T is castable to ISomethingSomething){
            var cast = cast Queryable<T> to Queryable<ISomethingSomething>;
            cast = SolveTheAnnoyingProblem(cast);
            query = cast the cast back to Queryable<T>;
        }
        //do more stuff
        //use query<T> to generate SomeReturn<T> someReturn*
        //*THIS is where I want to enumerate the query
        return someReturn;
    }

    public Queryable<ISomethingSomething> SolveTheAnnoyingProblem(Queryable<ISomethingSomething> query){
        //do stuff to this queryable
        return query;
    }
}
```

Comment: That´s why we have [generic constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters). I suppose you want `where T: class, ISomethingSomething`.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't realize it could be two things at once and function as either. I'll see how this plays out, thanks a ton!

Comment: The constraint isn't either, it is both. Though I would think an `ISomething` constraint would be sufficient to imply `class`.

Comment: Like I mentioned in the question, I attempted to replace "class" with "ISomething". It resulted in a rabbit hole of errors where I had to replace "where TEntity: class" with "where TEntity: ISomething", and then when I hit the ORM library that I couldn't change, I was forced to abandon that route. Defining it as both "TEntity: class, ISomething" seems to be doing the trick, though! And I just removed ISomething from one of the partial classes and confirmed I got build errors that way, so it looks like I lucked out and all existing implementations were already set up right haha